# Pygame isn't redrawing Rect as a different color

Tags: python, pygame

I'm attempting to make a grid of squares then change the color of the squares depending on their tag, But when I change the color it doesn't update on the pygame window display.

```
class Sq():
#init Func
    def __init__(self, surface, color, x, y, width=50, height=50):
        self.tag = 'normal'
        self.value = 1
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.surface = surface
        self.Sq = pygame.draw.rect(win.screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, 
        self.width,self.height))
        self.SQC = (self.Sq,self.tag )

     def DrawGrid(self):
        # Grid
        a1 = Sq(win.screen,(255,0,0),0,3,50,50)
        a2 = Sq(win.screen,(255,0,0),51,3,50,50)
        a3 = Sq(win.screen,(255,0,0),102,3,50,50)
        a4 = Sq(win.screen,(255,0,0),153,3,50,50)
        a5 = Sq(win.screen,(255,0,0),204,3,50,50)       

        #Square list
        SqL = [a1, a2, a3 ,a4 ,a5 ,a6 ,a7 ,a8 ,a9 ,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,b1 ,b2 ,b3 ,b4 ,b5 ,b6 ,b7 ,b8 ,b9 ,b10,b11,b12,b13,b14,b15,b16,etc...]     

        #This loop checks all the Square.tag and changes their color if they're tag is "normal"
        for self.i in SqL:
            if self.i.tag == 'normal': 
                self.i.color = (0,0,255)
                print(self.i.tag, self.i.color)
                pygame.display.update()

        #print check
        print(a1.color)
        pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop in `DrawGrid` updates the colors of your squares but you
don't draw these on your surface so it naturally doesn't update the
display.  You have to call something like `pygame.draw.rect` in your
for loop, because doing `self.i.color = (0,0,255)` is not enough.

Apart from that it seems odd that `DrawGrid` is a method of class
`Sq`.  Since `DrawGrid` draws a set of `Sq` it should be made a class
method of `Sq`.  Actually, when you look at its body, it does'nt use
`self` at all except the `for self.i in SqL` loop which should be
changed in `for sq in SqL` because using `self` here is irrelevant.
This is a good sign telling you that `DrawGrid` is a class method.